# CRC 8 value on STM doesnt match online calculators

Tags: c, stm32, crc

So I've been trying to learn CRC and tried to implement the same on my STM32G070 nucleo board. After setting up all the required configuration I'm returned an unexpected value. The website I used to verify my values http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html
My initial configuration was

Poly:0x31

Init:0xff

XOR: 00

no reflect on input and output

My configuration on the stm board are as per below

```
uint32_t crcCheck(uint32_t data)
{
    
    RCC->AHB1ENR                    |= (RCC_AHB1ENR_CRCEN);
    
    //RESET
    CRC->CR                             |= (CRC_CR_RESET);
    //8 BIT POLYNOMIAL
    CRC->CR                             |= (CRC_CR_POLYSIZE_1);
    CRC->POL                             = (0x31);
    CRC->INIT                            = (0xFF);
    CRC->DR                              = data;
    
    return CRC->DR;
}
```

for trial I provided 0x32 as input and got 0x0B from online calculator and 0x70 from my program which does not matches. However I noted something strange that when I keep the inital poly as 0X00, both of them gave me 0xA7 as an output. I've tried for a while but could not arrive on a conclusion for this behavior.

Comment: The code sample never actually performs the CRC check. It just sets `CRC->DR` then reads it back and returns it.

Comment: @AlexF I tried with your given settings it still doesn't match

Comment: @Locke the function name might be a bit misleading but I manually check the value returned by the function on the debugger and then compare it with the online calculator.

Comment: @plantPlanter and how do you know the mcu was done with the calculation?

Comment: Whats `CRC_CR_POLYSIZE_1` expanding to? According to the manual you need binary 10 for 8 bit poly. Writing 01 gives a 16 bit one.

Comment: @Fredrik I just check the CRC_DR register using the debugger. As per the reference manual the calculation is done in 1 cycle, so its immediate. As I write to my value to the register, I can see its value changes to the crc output value. It doesn't change throughout the rest of the program as I hop around other functions

Comment: @Lundin ```CRC_CRCPOLYSIZE_1 ``` does expand to the binary 10 for 8 bit poly. It basically means that it is setting the bit 1 hence 10 and not 01

Comment: Okay. It does smell like an issue with 32 bit registers for 8 bit calculations though. You could try to set the whole INIT register to 0xFFFFFFFF I suppose. It's apparently set like that after reset.

Comment: @Lundin Tried it right now, same result 0x70 instead of 0x0B

Comment: 0x70 is the whole 32 bit register value?

Comment: @Lundin yes the value I receive is 0x00000070

Comment: Shouldn't it be 0x70000000 for little endian? I noticed that the hardware has support for various endianess. CRC is normally calculated as big endian actually, since pure hardware implementations with XOR gates require that format.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure about that. Yes it supports various endianess but the output that it provides me is 0x00000070. Also the thing is it with the '''CRC_INIT''' value of 0x00, the output starts to match with the online calculators.

Comment: Try `*((volatile uint8_t *)&CRC->DR) =  data;`.

Comment: @MarkAdler I tried your suggestion, now it returns 0xEC. Something changed but no the required result

Comment: @MarkAdler That would be the same thing as telling the CRC hardware to use little endian.

Comment: @MarkAdler I accidentally left the the reverse input option enabled last time and after disabling it now it does return the required 0x0B and works with all INIT values! Thank you very much !

Comment: So to summarize: all Cortex M I know of are little endian. If you view a 32 bit value in some higher layer thing like a `uint32_t` watch in your debugger, it will show as `0x00000070` but it will actually be stored in memory as `0x70, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00`. Since CRC can go either way endianess-wise, you have to be careful with what you put it, how you set the endianess config and what you grab from the result. Same endianess concerns apply whenever you use some serial bus or ADC etc.

Comment: @Lundin You will get a different CRC if you process 32 bits vs. 8 bits, regardless if the other 24 bits are zero or not.

Comment: @MarkAdler Yes of course but we already verified that wasn't the case.